# Simulation shows my op Amp has a gain for infinite frequency spectrum

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I (could not) have designed an Op Amp and made the AC simulation on LtSpice and I saw something annoys me as below:

[image: AC domain Analysis]

and here is the schematic, a pretty basic op amp structure:

[image: Op Amp topology]

As you see, at least 10 dB gain is seen through frequency(I simulated up to 100 GHz still same!) domain. How is this possible? Eventhough, I could not design the Op Amp well, isn't this impossible?

I use these directives as seen on schematic:

.MODEL TestP PMOS (KP=60u VT0=-0.5 LAMBDA=0.01)
.MODEL TestN NMOS (KP=120u VT0=0.5 LAMBDA=0.01)

And I have tested it, it works fine. But I do not understand why am I getting a result like this. It is a first for me. So can you suggest anything to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably missing a lot of parasitic capacitance, resistance and inductance.

Comment: It might be, but would not it cause to decrease the gain? instead of increasing it to 10 dB?

Comment: I think you measured just the open-loop gain. Then 10dB would be much to low.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Yes I measured the open loop gain.

Comment: Pipe is right, you are missing parasitics.  Especially the load capacitance.

Comment: An op-amp requires a high [open-loop gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-loop_gain), so that, the closed-loop gain is almost only defined by the resistors, etc., connected outside.

Comment: What do you think is wrong about what you see in the graphs? I see nothing that concerns.

Comment: You don't have any inductance for any traces (even chip-level ones have some). Add some and you'll see how the 100GHz amp fares... Also parasitic capacitances to ground. You can add those with a single command for all nodes... but I don't remember it off top of my head.

Comment: There's a `.options cshunt=` but it seems it only works for transient analysis, so won't do anything for AC sweep alas. You'd have to add parasitics manually for that, it seems.

Comment: @Andy aka I concern about the stability of the op Amp. Phase margin is above 180 degree. It will be unstable. I think?

Comment: @Respawned, thanks for the reply. I understand now, but which scale of inductances and capacitances will be good for this design according to you may I ask?

Comment: I'm no analog IC designer. You'd have to lookup those for the process you intend this for, even if it's just a simulation.

Comment: OK I see what you mean - the flat +10dB line extending to "infinity" - yes this looks like an over-simplistic model in LTSpice.

Comment: What is the DC offset voltage of the sources V2 and V3? I hope not zero because then the transistors at the inputs (in the middle, numbers are not readable) will be cut-off and the results meaningless. The DC output voltage is also not well-defined because you connected two (non-ideal) current sources together: drain of upper right p-MOSFET and drain of lower right n-MOSFET.

Comment: DC offSet of each is 2V in ICMR range. DC output Voltage is a litle below VDD/2 and VDD is 3.3 V

Answer (score 2):

The model is too simple. More specifically, the MOSFET models are too simple. Spice models like these don't have any built in bandwidth limits (how could they?), unless you add them. More realistic FETs will have values defined for CGD0 and CGS0. With those in place you'd find high frequency poles to roll off the gain.

But, you can learn a lot with simple models like this. Even models that are too simple. It allows you to look at the effects of some single thing in isolation.

In this case there is one part to limit bandwidth, C1, the Miller capacitor. So, you can see, in isolation, how Miller feedback works. Miller feedback is the most common method of compensating an OpAmp.

Looking at the Bode plot, you can see the low frequency pole provided by Miller feedback. But, at about 5MHz, you also see a zero, that causes the gain to flatten out. It's a special kind of zero. What kind of zero causes loss of phase?

Anyway, simple Miller feedback like this is, always provides a low frequency pole and that funny acting zero that makes the OpAmp loose phase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was suppose to work in this process however, there is no way to find out which valur is the Threshold voltage and which value is un*Cox:http://ptm.asu.edu/modelcard/2006/130nm_bulk.pm

Comment: @Alper - KP = Uo Cox =( Uo \$\epsilon _o \epsilon _r\$)/Tox. Does LtSpice support the linked process?

Answer (score 2):

I have used Qucs to simulate you circuit and here the gain keeps dropping for very high frequencies. So the question was: what may be different to the model used by LTspice?

It turns out, that Qucs automatically calculates a gate capacitance from the specified channel length and width, as well as the thickness of the gate oxide. If I set length and width to unrealistic 1 nm, the gate capacitance would be very low. After simulating the circuit again, the gain drops only to 10 dB and then keeps there for high frequencies.

By the way, there must be another difference because I got a DC voltage of around 0.2V at the output which is different to the posted VDD/2 in the comments.

Comment: Oh thank you, I am downloading qucs now for a try. However, I did not give away the transistor sizes. How can those two results be the same?

Comment: The results are not exactly the same, as also my last paragraph indicates. But, in most model equations (except gate capacitance) only the ratio between channel width and length is of importance.